# AlamofireImage af_cancelImageRequest affects Alamofire.request when called quickly when user scrolls collection view very fast

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionviewcell, alamofire

Collection view cell displays images with AlamofireImage. 
Alamofire.request fetches JSON with URLs for each image category.
User selects image category (fetch JSON with image URLs) and navigates horizontal collection view. Goes back to the menu, selects category and so on.

My problem is that after I scroll collection view very fast and then try to fetch JSON for another images category, Alamofire.request callback never gets called.

In the cell I set image with url:

```
self.imageView.af_setImageWithURL(url, imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.25))
```

Do the clean up just the same way it's done in the AlamofireImage Sample's project:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()   

    imageView.af_cancelImageRequest()
    imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    imageView.image = nil
    ...
}
```

I've noticed that this issue never happens if I remove `imageView.af_cancelImageRequest()` from `prepareForReuse()`

I'm curious - am I missing something or is it an AlamofireImage bug?